# "Can't have a partition outside the disk!" for vdi created from a truncated image

Tags: partition, virtualbox, fdisk, gparted, disk-image

I have used `dd` to create a partial/truncated image of a disk which only includes allocated spaces, then converted it to a vdi file for VirtualBox. I have successfully used the vdi image to run the Linux (Ubuntu) which was installed on the disk.

Now I wan't to run GParted to remove partitions which are located before the Linux partition (so that I can create a smaller image). But GParted doesn't work. It shows entire disk as unallocated. How can I fix it?

Additional info:

**sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print**

```
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
```

**sudo fdisk -l -u /dev/sda**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 97.7 GB, 97729379840 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 11881 cylinders, total 190877695 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3c36156a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2459647     1228800    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         2459648   125339129    61439741    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       125339646   190877695    32769025    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       125339648   190877695    32769024   83  Linux
```

**sudo sfdisk -uS -l /dev/sda**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 11881 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.
Units = sectors of 512 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot    Start       End   #sectors  Id  System
/dev/sda1   *      2048   2459647    2457600   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       2459648 125339129  122879482   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3     125339646 190877695   65538050   5  Extended
/dev/sda4             0         -          0   0  Empty
/dev/sda5     125339648 190877695   65538048  83  Linux
```

**sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda**

```
Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.
# partition table of /dev/sda
unit: sectors

/dev/sda1 : start=     2048, size=  2457600, Id= 7, bootable
/dev/sda2 : start=  2459648, size=122879482, Id= 7
/dev/sda3 : start=125339646, size= 65538050, Id= 5
/dev/sda4 : start=        0, size=        0, Id= 0
/dev/sda5 : start=125339648, size= 65538048, Id=83
```

Comment: Hint: Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest solution would be to increase the size of the image to make `gparted` happy again. This most probably is a one-off kind of issue, so increasing the image size by a couple of additional megabytes could be enough:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=newimage.raw bs=1M count=102400
qemu-img convert -f vdi oldimage.vdi -O raw oldimage.raw
dd if=oldimage.raw of=newimage.raw count=190877695 conv=notrunc
qemu-img convert -f raw newimage.raw -O vdi newimage.vdi
```

Or simply:

```
cp oldimage.vdi newimage.vdi
VBoxManage modifyhd /path/to/newimage.vdi --resize 102400
```

Then you should retry to run `gparted` on `newimage.vdi`. If it still complains, you may try to increase the size of the image to the original disk size, provided you have enough space.

Comment: Thanks, second method didn't work, but first one solved my issue (just instead of first line I appended enough zero to oldimage.raw to resize it to next GB).

Comment: To be honest, I never used VirtualBox on Linux and I have no idea what are the prerequisites for an image to be resizable with `VBoxManage` command. Glad to hear your issue is solved!